# strange error : Skipping entry 0x106000d in package table 0 because it is not complex

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

i get an error :

```
12-27 20:53:21.874: W/ResourceType(829): Skipping entry 0x106000d in package table 0 because it is not complex!
```

code:

```
private void change(final String txt , final int res , final int max , int seconds , final boolean s) {
    i = 1;
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(i <= max){
                int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(txt.replaceAll("i", String.valueOf(i).toString()), "id", getPackageName());
                ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(resourceId);
                imageButton.setBackgroundResource(res);
                if(s) {sound();}
                i++;
            }else{
                this.cancel();
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    },0,seconds);
}

private void change2(final int res , final int c ,final int r , final int seconds , final boolean s) {
    i = 1;
    u = 1;
    final Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(i <= c){
            final Timer timer2 = new Timer();
            timer2.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        if(u <= r){
                            int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("c"+i+"_r"+u, "id", getPackageName());
                            ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(resourceId);
                            imageButton.setBackgroundResource(res);
                            if(s) {sound();}
                            u++;
                        }else{
                            this.cancel();
                            timer2.cancel();
                        }
                    }
            },0,seconds);}else{
                this.cancel();
                timer1.cancel();
            }
        }
    },0,seconds);
}

public void onClickNext(View v){
    change2(R.drawable.white_circle,left_num,right_num,250,false);
    change("c"+left_num+"_ri", R.drawable.red_circle , right_num , 500 , true);
    change("c"+left_num+"_ri", R.drawable.white_circle , right_num , 500 , false);
    change("ci"+"_r"+left_num, R.drawable.green_circle , left_num , 500 , true);
    change("ci"+"_r"+left_num, R.drawable.white_circle , left_num , 500 , false);
    change2(R.drawable.yellow_circle,left_num,right_num,250,true);
}
```

and in xml I have 10x10 `ImageButton` , `c1_r1` to `c10_r10` , When c is `Column` and r is `Raw`.

and because i have many many `ImageButton`s , i tried to get id by string.

and i used `Timer` and `TimerTask` for pause some time before next change.

for any questions , type in comments.

Sorry for complex code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a warning. Unless you are experiencing problems that is causing your application to crash etc etc, ignore it. The operating system logs all sorts of stuff that we as developers wind up simply having to ignore. Check this link if you having any problems:
http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.com/2010/12/skipping-entry-in-package-table-0.html

UPDATE:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

```
 public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

Added in API level 1

Return a resource identifier for the given resource name. A fully qualified resource name is of the form `"package:type/entry".` The first two components (package and type) are optional if defType and defPackage, respectively, are specified here.

**Note:** use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

Comment: not solve my problem :(

Comment: it is causing an crash?

Comment: yes , without show a crash message.

Comment: did you check the R file for the resource id?

Comment: yes , but i can't found it.

Comment: wait in the question you said you tried imageButton with id as strings.??? that won't work at all. you need to supply an ID always. change that and check.

Comment: it take many many time , i need to declare it `ImageButton` by `ImageButton` , is there easy way to do this ?

Comment: check my answer. i edited it. and no you need to use IDs. thats what android recommends. And please accept the answer and close the question if it helped.

Comment: if yoo see , in my change and change2 methods i use this way.

Comment: It is failing because you are not giving the correct parameters.. check the documentation link that i posted.. Return a resource identifier for the given resource name. A fully qualified resource name is of the form "package:type/entry". The first two components (package and type) are optional if defType and defPackage, respectively, are specified here.